# The dataframe object gets unresolved when trying to append a dictionary as a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am following the steps I found online for this issue, but it doesn't seems to make things any better.

My code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Fetching the csv rows to pandas DataFrame
user_df = pd.read_csv('data/users.csv')

# Doing extra work
new_user_ = [(int(user_df['id'].max()) + 1, request.form['username'], request.form.get('address'), request.form.get('city'), request.form['password'], list(), list(), 0.0)]
dfNew = pd.DataFrame(new_user_, columns=['id', 'username', 'address', 'city', 'password', 'orders', 'favorites', 'balance'])
user_df = user_df.append(dfNew, ignore_index=True)
```

The last part (appending) is what is causing the error:
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'user_df' referenced before assignment`

I am basically trying to add a dictionary to the DataFrame object as a new row.

Comment: Is this your *exact* code or did you define a function somewhere?

Comment: This is a part of the code. After the "doing extra work" comment the rest are inside a Flask signup function

Comment: Please post the full code or at least the full traceback, because as written this would not invoke an `UnboundLocaleError`